# Finding change of Basis Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

For P2(R)is the vector space of polynomials of degree at most 2.

a standard basis, B is given by $(1,x,x^2)$

C is also a basis given by $(x^2-x, x, -x^2+x+1)$

How do i find the change of matrix [C]<sub>B</sub> and then find [B]<sub>C</sub> ?
It would really mean a lot if I can get a solution to this.

Comment: I think it's relatively easy to generate the coefficients for the matrix $A$ so that
$$
A 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ x \\x^2
\end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x^2-x \\ x \\-x^2 +x +1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
don't you think? Just by observation ...

Comment: by writing $[C]_B$ and $[B]_c$ you mean the matrixes $[M]_C^B$ and $[M]_B^C$?

Comment: @MattiP. so correct me if i am wrong but my [C}<sub>B</sub>  \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\-1&1&1\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix} and [B}<sub>C</sub> is the inverse of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the matrix $[C]_B$ , Take each polynomial from C and make this equation :
for example : (definition of c is scalars)

$x^2-x=c_1*1+c_2*x+c_3*x^2$ (after you solve this , take the scalars and put them in a matrix a the first column)

$x=c_1*1+c_2*x+c_3*x^2$

$-x^2+x+1=c_1*1+c_2*x+c_3*x^2$

after you solve the three equations and put them in a matrix , this is the transformation matrix.

Do the same with the other basis but now (or find the inverse of the matrix) $\Rightarrow$ The left side of the equation will be a vector from the basis $B$ and the right side of the equation will be scalars multiplied by the vectors of the basis $C$.